# what is the difference between sssd (realm join) and net ads join?

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, sssd, ubuntu-20.04

I have been using ubuntu 18.04 with sssd to join my servers to my active directory domain for a while now. This worked quite nicely, enabling me to ssh to the servers with AD users and create samba shares with AD authentication as well.
what I usually do is set all the configuration files (krb5, sssd, smb.conf) and use `realm join` to join the server to the domain.

with Ubuntu 20 I followed my same procedure to join the server to the domain. However I encountered an error with my smb.conf file- the smbd service wouldn't start as long as I had the setting `security = ads` enabled.

In order to make it  work I had to run `net ads join` command (this is after I already ran `realm join`)- only then did the smbd service agree to start with `security = ads` setting enabled.

Now I am left with open questions: what is the difference between `net ads` and `realm`, and what has changed between ubuntu-18 and ubuntu-20?

Answer (score 2):

#### SSSD:

- does not support NTLM, but NTLM is insecure and obsolete
- is simpler to install (can be auto-configured using realmd)
- does more than just Active Directory (e.g. LDAP)

#### Samba/Winbind/net ads:

- is harder to secure due to its support for NTLM.
- does not support AD DNS Aging and Scavenging (i.e. detecting if DNS entries for servers that have been removed or updated)
- As of Oracle Linux 7, SSSD is the preferred tool, although Samba and Winbind remain fully supported.

Comment: Is it possible to have samba `security=ads` to work with sssd? How do I configure it?

Comment: I do not think you can do that.

Comment: Then why did it work with this configured up to ubuntu-20?

Answer (score 1):

Commenting on "Is it possible to have samba security=ads to work with sssd? How do I configure it?"

Adding below directives for smb.conf worked for me

```
    client signing = if_required
    kerberos method = secrets and keytab
    security = ads
    idmap config * : backend = tdb
    idmap config * : range = 3000-7999
    workgroup = YOURWORKGROUP
    realm = yourworkgroup.com
    idmap config YOURWORKGROUP:backend = ad
    idmap config YOURWORKGROUP:schema_mode = rfc2307
    idmap config YOURWORKGROUP:range = 10000-9999999
```

Refer to this wiki
https://wiki.debian.org/AuthenticatingLinuxWithActiveDirectorySssd